# My node.h is making continues requests and is saturating my bandwidth

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I install Ruby 1.9.3 on my server and since then my network is being affected by continues request made by the file node.h. I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Without additional information, it is not possible to find what is happening here. Please provide e.g. a stack trace, or at least a full file location. Also, please describe the application you use.

Comment: The file is located in /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p545/node.h and the other one is located at usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.11.2.e16.x86_64/include/linux/node.h and my application is a api that communicates with ipads via Rest services using Json as format.